# vertical alignment of text in tikz node

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment

The output from the following script

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node(title)[text width = 0.25\textwidth, text height = 3 cm, draw]{title};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

is

[image]

How can I vertically align the text in the node?

Specifying the `text depth` as in

```
\node(title)[text width = 0.25\textwidth, text height = 1cm, text depth = 1 cm, draw]{
    title line 1\\
    title line 2\\
    title line 3};
```

Does not result in the text being vertically centred.

[image]

Comment: `text height` specifies the height of the text, so adds space above the text. You could use `text depth` to specify a certain depth, which adds space below your text. But I guess you don't want that, either. You're most likely looking for `minimum size` instead of `text height`.

Comment: @Skillmon, could I centre text following your suggestion of using `text depth`? See my updated question. – Viesturs

Comment: No, use `minimum size` or `minimum height`, the latter if it's just about vertical dimensions (you already specified horizontal dimensions with `text width`).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`text height` and `text depth` specify the vertical dimensions of the text you give explicitly. As a result Ti*k*Z thinks the node's text has exactly that height and draws its box like that.

You can use `minimum height` to set a minimum vertical size of the node, and `minimum width` for the width (while `text width` inserts line wrapping at the specified width `minimum width` does not). The result will be a box in which your text is centred, but the box must have at least those dimensions. Note that `minimum height` is both height and depth around your text (evenly). If you want line wrapping text which is horizontally centred you can use `text width` and `text centered`.

Compare the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
  \node(1)[text centered,text width = 0.25\textwidth, minimum height = 3 cm, draw]
    {title is very long and long};
  \node(2)[minimum width = 0.25\textwidth, minimum height = 3 cm,
    draw,below of=1,anchor=north]{title is very long and long};
  \node(3)[text centered,text width = 0.25\textwidth, text height = 3 cm,
    draw,below of=2,anchor=north]{title is very long and long};
  \node(4)[text centered,text width = 0.25\textwidth, text depth = 3 cm,
    draw,below of=3,anchor=north]{title is very long and long};
  \node(5)[text centered,text width = 0.25\textwidth, text depth = 1.5 cm, text
    height = 1.5cm, draw,below of=4,anchor=north]{title is very long and long};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to fix the position of the baseline independently of the content of the node? Indeed, if I fix `text height=.3em,text depth=0em` then the baseline is always at the same position but if the text is particularly heigh then it will go out of the node. MWE:  `\tikzset{my/.style={font={\fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont\boldmath},minimum size=5mm, inner sep=0pt, anchor=center,circle,fill=red,text height=.3em,text depth=0em}}
\tikz \node[my]{$a$}; \tikz \node[my]{$b$}; \tikz \node[my]{$b\pi'$};`

Comment: @tobiasBora first: That might be better off as a new question. However, take a look at the `baseline` key. E.g., use `\tikz[baseline=<something>]\node[my]{$b$};` (with `<something>` some length Ti*k*Z understands, might reference the current bounding box as well)

Comment: @Skillmon, I'd like as node 4 but with constant total height. For example, 4cm with text pushed to top. The text could have 1, 2 or even 3 lines but the text should go to top always. Is it possible?

Comment: @Sigur I'm not sure whether there are built-in options to achieve that, but note that nothing hinders you to use `\parbox` inside of a `node`: `\node[draw]{\parbox[t][4cm][t]{5cm}{Your node text goes here};` creates a 4cm high and 5cm wide node (plus `inner sep`) with the contents at the top.

Comment: @Skillmon, thanks. I tried it and also another possibility is to subtract a little bit: `text depth=4cm - 14pt` worked in my case. Thanks.