# Vertical alignment of node contents

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, tikz-node

In TikZ, I know that the relevant properties to control the shape and text-alignment of a node are:

- `minimum width` and `minimum height` (outer shape)
- AFAIU `baseline` is used to align the nodes themselves, not their contents?
- `align` (section [17.4.3](http://pgf.sourceforge.net/pgf_CVS.pdf))
- `text width` and `text height` (section [17.4.4](http://pgf.sourceforge.net/pgf_CVS.pdf)), although the documentation mentions that:

> I recommend using minimum size instead of text height except for special situations.

I also think that [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430004/26497) gives a very good example of how to use these properties with text.

---

But what if what if the contents I am trying to align are **not** text? 
My example below is using a `minipage`, but if that doesn't change the answer completely, I would assume this could be a `tabular`, or `includegraphics`, or any other non-text contents.

As you can see the alignment of the contents is vertically centred. **Given that I have specified `minimum height/width`, how can I specify an alignment to the top of the node, or to the bottom?**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength{\boxH} \setlength{\boxH}{2cm}
\newlength{\boxW} \setlength{\boxW}{5cm}
\newlength{\boxM} \setlength{\boxM}{2mm}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[
        shape=rectangle, 
        fill=red, 
        inner sep=\boxM, 
        minimum width=\boxW, 
        minimum height=\boxH, 
        anchor=north west
    ] {%
        \begin{minipage}{\boxW-2\boxM}%
        One line
        \end{minipage}%
    };
    \node[
        shape=rectangle, 
        fill=blue, 
        xshift=\boxW+\boxM,
        inner sep=\boxM, 
        minimum width=\boxW, 
        minimum height=\boxH, 
        anchor=north west
    ] {%
        \begin{minipage}{\boxW-2\boxM}%
        Two\\ lines
        \end{minipage}%
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of example drawing]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are already using minipages, you could use their alignment mechanisms. For example, it you want the text in the red box to be top aligned, use

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength{\boxH} \setlength{\boxH}{2cm}
\newlength{\boxW} \setlength{\boxW}{5cm}
\newlength{\boxM} \setlength{\boxM}{2mm}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[
        shape=rectangle, 
        fill=red, 
        inner sep=\boxM, 
        minimum width=\boxW, 
        minimum height=\boxH, 
        anchor=north west
    ] {%
        \begin{minipage}[t][\the\dimexpr\boxH-1.6em]{\boxW-2\boxM}%
        One line
        \end{minipage}%
    };
    \node[
        shape=rectangle, 
        fill=blue, 
        xshift=\boxW+\boxM,
        inner sep=\boxM, 
        minimum width=\boxW, 
        minimum height=\boxH, 
        anchor=north west
    ] {%
        \begin{minipage}{\boxW-2\boxM}%
        Two\\ lines
        \end{minipage}%
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Since node's size is fixed and you know it's large enough to contain the text, you can use a `label` to place the text inside node's border selecting the convenient `anchor`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength{\boxH} \setlength{\boxH}{2cm}
\newlength{\boxW} \setlength{\boxW}{5cm}
\newlength{\boxM} \setlength{\boxM}{2mm}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[
        shape=rectangle, 
        fill=red, 
        inner sep=\boxM, 
        minimum width=\boxW, 
        minimum height=\boxH, 
        anchor=north west,
        label={[anchor=north west]north west:One line}
    ] {};
    \node[
        shape=rectangle, 
        fill=blue, 
        xshift=\boxW+\boxM,
        inner sep=\boxM, 
        minimum width=\boxW, 
        minimum height=\boxH, 
        anchor=north west,
        label={[anchor=south, align=left]south:{Two\\ longer lines}}
    ] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139723/28557) gives an alternate way of doing it.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength{\boxH} \setlength{\boxH}{2cm}
\newlength{\boxW} \setlength{\boxW}{5cm}
\newlength{\boxM} \setlength{\boxM}{2mm}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[
        shape=rectangle, 
        fill=red, 
        inner sep=\boxM, 
        minimum width=\boxW, 
        minimum height=\boxH, 
        anchor=north west,
        append after command={node[anchor=north west] at  (\tikzlastnode.north west) 
        {\begin{minipage}{\boxW-2\boxM}%
          One line
        \end{minipage}}},
    ] {};
    \node[
        shape=rectangle, 
        fill=blue, 
        xshift=\boxW+\boxM,
        inner sep=\boxM, 
        minimum width=\boxW, 
        minimum height=\boxH, 
        anchor=north west,
        append after command={
        node[anchor=south west] at  (\tikzlastnode.south west) 
        {\begin{minipage}{\boxW-2\boxM}%
          Two\\ lines
        \end{minipage}}},
    ] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```