# tikz: Vertically centered aligned node text

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, tikz-node

I want to align the node text vertically centered. Wondering how to accomplish this?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, fit, calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font = \normalsize]
  \begin{scope}[every node/.style={%
  text width     = 3.0cm, 
  text depth     = 2.0cm,
  inner sep      = 2.0mm,
  minimum height = 2.0cm,
  minimum width  = 1.5cm,
  align          = left
  }]

\node[fill = blue!20](T1){\textbf{F}};

 \node[fill = red!20, anchor = north west](T2) at (T1.north east){\textbf{Co}};

\node[fill = green!20, anchor = north west](T3) at (T1.south west){\textbf{Cu}};

\node[fill = yellow!20, anchor = north west](T4) at (T1.south east){\textbf{O}}; 
\end{scope}


\begin{scope}[align = center]
 \node [text width = 6cm, above = 0.0ex, anchor = south] (T5) at (T1.north east) {\textbf{I}};

 \node [text width = 6cm, below = 0.0ex, anchor = north] (T6) at (T3.south east) {\textbf{U}}; 


 \node [text width = 1.5cm, left = 0.0ex, anchor = east](T7) at (T1.south west) {\textbf{C}};

 \node [text width = 0.75cm, right = 0.0ex, anchor = west](T8) at (T2.south east) {\textbf{S}};

\end{scope}

\draw[thick] (T5) -- (T6)
             (T7) -- (T8) ;   
\end{tikzpicture} 
 
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Solution**
Just removing `text width = 3.0cm, text depth = 2.0cm` from my working example gives the required solution.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, fit, calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font = \normalsize]
  \begin{scope}[every node/.style={%
%  text width     = 3.0cm, 
%  text depth     = 2.0cm,
  inner sep      = 2.0mm,
  minimum height = 2.0cm,
  minimum width  = 1.5cm,
  align          = left
  }]

\node[fill = blue!20](T1){\textbf{F}};

 \node[fill = red!20, anchor = north west](T2) at (T1.north east){\textbf{Co}};

\node[fill = green!20, anchor = north west](T3) at (T1.south west){\textbf{Cu}};

\node[fill = yellow!20, anchor = north west](T4) at (T1.south east){\textbf{O}}; 
\end{scope}


\begin{scope}[align = center]
 \node [text width = 6cm, above = 0.0ex, anchor = south] (T5) at (T1.north east) {\textbf{I}};

 \node [text width = 6cm, below = 0.0ex, anchor = north] (T6) at (T3.south east) {\textbf{U}}; 


 \node [text width = 1.5cm, left = 0.0ex, anchor = east](T7) at (T1.south west) {\textbf{C}};

 \node [text width = 0.75cm, right = 0.0ex, anchor = west](T8) at (T2.south east) {\textbf{S}};

\end{scope}

\draw[thick] (T5) -- (T6)
             (T7) -- (T8) ;   
\end{tikzpicture} 
 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430004/197451

Comment: @JasperHabicht: Please provide the best possible solution.

Comment: No, sorry, your solution is fine if this is the intended outcome.